# Replace Light Locker with Gnome screensaver

Tags: screensaver, gnome-tweak-tool, gnome-screensaver, light-locker

There have been many issues reported concerning Light Locker. Sometimes the lock doesn't work, it locks by itself when not supposed to and many more. Bottom line is Light Locker's major issue is, it doesn't hold the applied or user settings after a reboot or log out.

Comment: ... and your question is the topic?

Answer (score 6):

Tried many workarounds to no avail. The way I solved this issue was by removing Light-Locker completely and installing gnome screensaver.

**Replace Light-Locker with Gnome Screensaver:**

- Start *Synaptic Package Manager*.
- Type `light-locker`, then uncheck `light-locker` and `light-locker-settings` and click [Apply changes].
- Then type `gnome-screensaver` and check the box to the left and click apply changes again.

Or, using the terminal:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge light-locker
sudo apt-get install gnome-screensaver
```

It works perfectly, didn't mess up my configuration with `lightdm`, and looks good too. If you're not satisfied with the background shown every time you lock your screen, you can install `gnome-tweak-tool`. If you can't find it in the applications menu, you can either run it through terminal `gnome-tweak-tool` or or create a launcher using the same command. Once it's open go to the desktop tab, and choose the location of the background of your liking.

[image: Gnome Tweak Tool screenshot]

Now you can lock your screen and enjoy a nice screensaver/locking application that works! Good luck! :)

Comment: Could you maybe provide the package names of packages removed and installed? (Or, even better, the full commands used.)

Comment: go to synaptic package manager and type light-locker. uncheck  lightlocker and lightlocker-settings. Click apply changes. The same way type gnome-screensaver and check the box to the left. Click apply changes.  If you want to use the terminal type sudo apt-get remove --purge light-locker. then to install gnome-screensaver type sudo apt-get install gnome-screensaver and you're good to go.

Comment: The information given in your comment really should go into the answer, so I edited it. Feel free to improve upon my edits though.